# Constrain gradient to circle

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I've a Canvas into which I'm drawing a circle with a gradient fill.

I draw this circle at different places as the user moves it, and what's immediately obvious is that the gradient is being scaled to the full Canvas and the effect of drawCircle is to give a window on that gradient that changes colour as you move the circle. Is there a way to apply a gradient just to the circle so that the appearance does not change when the circle is at different places in the Canvas?

The full code to reproduce is

```
package com.example.joysticksandpit

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.Canvas
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectDragGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.gestures.detectTapGestures
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset
import androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Size
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Brush
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.consumeAllChanges
import androidx.compose.ui.input.pointer.pointerInput
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import com.example.joysticksandpit.ui.theme.JoystickSandpitTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            JoystickSandpitTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    GradientTest()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun GradientTest() {
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(0.9f)) {
        drawCircle(
            Brush.radialGradient(colors = listOf(Color.Red, Color.White)),
            radius = 50f,
            center = Offset(300f, 300f)
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Post the full code to reproduce the issue

Answer (score 0):

This was a somewhat silly oversight but I decided to keep and answer rather than deleting in case someone else is googling.

Brush.radialGradient has parameters for center and radius, which allow the gradient to be positioned as required.

```
public final fun radialGradient(
    colors: List<Color>,
    center: Offset,
    radius: Float,
    tileMode: TileMode
): Brush
```